# Why do I need to use static here? It doesn't seem like I'd need it in this case

Tags: java

I've just recently picked up Java. This is my first day of coding. I have two classes. One is a class that gets user input and outputs it, and another is a class with its own methods and variables.

CLASS 1:

```
public class Player {
    // this is my player class
    private static int health;

    public void setHealth(int healthToSet) {
        health = healthToSet;
    }

    public static int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }
}
```

CLASS 2:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Obtainer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number you'd like to set your health    to...");
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int givenInt = userInput.nextInt();

        Player newPlayer = new Player();

        newPlayer.setHealth(givenInt);

        int newHealth = Player.getHealth();

        System.out.println("OK, you have set your health to " +       newHealth);

        userInput.close();
    }

}
```

Eclipse prompted me to add a static modifier my getHealth method. I didn't need to do this with setHealth, after doing private int health; instead of private int health = 100;. I know it says static, but that's after I added the static modifier to that and getHealth after I was prompted to. What is the point of this? What is the difference between getHealth and setHealth aside from the fact that setHealth returns no value and getHealth returns a value? Is that what's making me need to use a static modifier?

Comment: Please don't take it offending - IMHO stackoverflow is not the place for such "learning programming" questions. Please consult some good book on OOP and Java to learn Java programming.

Comment: @RaviH Yes, this is just your opinion.  This question is laid out well, shows some thought and research and does not deserve to be downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `int newHealth = Player.getHealth();` to `int newHealth = newPlayer.getHealth();`

Since you are currently invoking the method on a class and not an object, the method has to be static, therefore the compiler complains if it is not.

Comment: Crazy how I didn't notice that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this case I would not use static variables or method, so I would change to

```
private int health;

public int getHealth() {...}

int newHealth = newPlayer.getHealth();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the instance methods with the class name.

Option 1 :
`newPlayer.getHealth();`

Option 2 : 
add the static modifier to `getHealth()` if it needs to access by Class name.